Selectize not showing results that starts with the character Ñ
I have a list with several options but the search is not showing the element that start with the Ñ character. If this character is in the middle of the string, it has no problems. here i copy the code ii am using to see if anything is wrong here.
function obtentores(element) {
  jQuery(element).selectize({
    options: [
      { obtentor: 'DON MARIO', cultivo: "TRIGO", variedad: "CRONOX", value: "DON MARIO: TRIGO | CROÑOX" },
      { obtentor: 'DON MARIO', cultivo: "TRIGO", variedad: "FUSTE", value: "DON MARIO: TRIGO | FUSTE" },
      { obtentor: 'DON MARIO', cultivo: "TRIGO", variedad: "LENGA", value: "DON MARIO: TRIGO | LENGA" },
      { obtentor: 'DON MARIO', cultivo: "TRIGO", variedad: "LENOX", value: "DON MARIO: TRIGO | LENOX" },
      { obtentor: 'DON MARIO', cultivo: "TRIGO", variedad: "LYON", value: "DON MARIO: TRIGO | LYON" },
      { obtentor: 'DON MARIO', cultivo: "TRIGO", variedad: "DMÑANDUBAY", value: "DON MARIO: TRIGO | ÑANDUBAY" },
    ],
    optionGroupRegister: function(optgroup) {
      var capitalised = optgroup.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + optgroup.substring(1);
      var group = {
        label: 'Obtentor: ' + capitalised
      };
      group[this.settings.optgroupValueField] = optgroup;
      return group;
    },
    render: {
      item: function(item, escape) {
        return (
          "<div>" +
            (item.variedad ? '<span class="name">' + escape(item.variedad) + "</span>" : "") +
          "</div>"
        );
      },
      option: function(item, escape) {
        var label = item.variedad;
        var caption = item.cultivo;
        return (
          "<div style='display: flex; justify-content: space-between; padding: 4px 8px'>" +
          "<span class='label'>" +
          escape(label) +
          "</span>" +
          (caption ?
            '<span class="caption">' + escape(caption) + "</span>" :
            "") +
          "</div>"
        );
      },
    },
    maxOptions: 100,
    placeholder: 'Ingrese su busqueda ...',
    optgroupField: 'obtentor',
    labelField: 'variedad',
    searchField: ['variedad', 'obtentor', 'cultivo'],
    sortField: 'variedad'
  });
}

I need that the search shows the result with the Ñ in any position.

Provably because it doesn't know that ñ and Ñ should be treated the same when searching case-in sensitively, could that be? That would happen if toLowerCase/toUpperCase (which are only aware of ASCII) were used instead of toLocaleLowerCase/toLocaleUpperCase.
